# No puedo conectarme a MYSQL con python

Tags: mysql, python

Estoy utilizando **PyMySql**. Solo quiero hacer una "Query" sencilla:

```
   SELECT * FROM python_1
```

Siempre obtengo este error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Alumnos.py", line 5, in <module>
    connection = pymysql.connect('localhost','d3h','','python')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 90, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 706, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 932, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1152, in _request_authentication
    auth_packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 1014, in _read_packet
    packet.check_error()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 393, in check_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 107, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'd3h'@'localhost' (using password: NO)")
```

He revisado la sintaxis varias veces y no veo algún problema.

Aquí mi código:

```
import pymysql.cursor
connection = pymysql.connect('localhost','d3h','','python')
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        query = "SELECT * FROM python_1"
        cursor.execute(query)
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

**PD**: Utilizo c9.io

Comment: El mensaje de error te dice claramente lo que pasa: *Access denied for user 'd3h'@'localhost' (using password: NO)*. Verifica las credenciales de MySQL.

Comment: "Access denied for user 'd3h'@'localhost' (using password: NO)."  El caso es que con PHP si hay funcionado. Por ello supuse que mi usuario no era el problema, igual verificare las credenciales como tu dices. Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok esta es la forma que yo uso para declarar el conector

```
connection = pymysql.connect(host='192.168.0.38',
                            user='root',
                            password='12345',
                            db='mi_basede_datos',
                            charset='utf8mb4',
                            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

pero aparentemente el error esta en la gestion de usuarios, tu usuario debe tener permisos para modificar y leer la base de datos y tambien debe tener contrasena si o si, es un metodo de seguridad que tiene mysql

Comment: Entonces es siempre necesario utilizar contraseña? Vi varios ejemplos sin contraseñas supongo que estaban mal. Probare lo que dice, y te cuento si funciona.

Comment: Verifique que mi usuario tiene los permisos para modificar y leer la base datos, agregue la contraseña, pero igual me daba el mismo error, pero "(using password: SI)". Asi que utilize tu forma para declara el conector, y funciono!. El problema para conectarme a la base de datos esta resuelto. Aunque no estoy muy seguro si era la contraseña o el código. Gracias!

Comment: elimina la contrasena y pruebas a ver y me cuentas, no puedo quedarme con la duda

Comment: Elimine la contraseña y funciono con normalidad. Eso explica porque en los ejemplos aparecían sin contraseñas. Asumo que fue el código.

Comment: gracias, entonces si era el conector